# MIDI or OSC controls between browsers

Tags: browser, xmpp, midi, osc, synchronization

I'm looking into the possibility of simple music snychronisation and control (MIDI / OSC) between mobile browsers, XMPP would seem promising, but I've found no suitable extensions. Have you any useful pointers?

Moreover, do you feel xmpp could be the way to go, or are there better alternatives? "In-browser" really would be a must.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try sending synchronization commands over [XEP-0060](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html).  You can make up whatever XML you like to publish.